# Is it possible to use the same arguments to both decorator and function

Tags: python-2.7, arguments, decorator

I need to understand how I can access the variable that was passed to the function in the decorator.

Let me explain with an example, is it possible to do something like this:

```
class test(object):
    ....
    @DecoratorClass(myWrapper(self, x))
    def myFunction(self, x):
        print x
        print self.y
```

At some point an instance of the `test-class` is created, and `myFunction` is called from somewhere. I need to path the same argument to `myWrapper`.

I hope that this is clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decorator replaces the function with a callable that wraps it, so the callable will be passed the same parameters as the original function. So, for example:

```
def Decorator(original_function):
  def replacement_function(x):
    # You now have 'x' here... do what you want with it.
  return replacement_function

@Decorator
def MyFunction(x):
   # ...
```

Note that you will need to delay construction of "myWrapper" until the function is executed (because you will not have the function parameter until then).

Comment: thanks, but what should be done if I need the arguments to construct a propeer myWrapper?